# JPanel inside a JFrame, JFrame is not resizing according to the size of the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to size the Frame according to the size of the JPanel, but it is not working properly. The following is the code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
```

That is creating a JFrame with [width=10,height=32]

Comment: What matters is the **preferred** size.

Comment: I tried using the preferred size already and still giving the same dimensions, not resizing the Frame

Comment: Ok I made it work with preferred size, no idea why it wasn't working before. Thank you